# can't launch nodejs program, socket : (87) the parameter is incorrect

Tags: node.js, sockets

i have installed nodejs on my windows 7  ultimate x64. 
The installation was successful but when i tried to open the command line and type npm or node its show this message:

> socket: (87) The parameter is incorrect. Your environment has been
>   set up for using Node.js  and npm.
>
> C:\Users\Serge>node socket: (87) The parameter is incorrect.
>
> C:\Users\Serge>npm socket: (87) The parameter is incorrect. socket:
>   (87) The parameter is incorrect.
>
> C:\Users\Serge>

do not hesitate to leave your comments. 
thank you!

Comment: Are you running any security software that might be getting in the way? Did you try using an Administrator command prompt?

Comment: i have advanved systemcare on my pc but i dnt think it is the cause. they said the "87 error " is a windows error. so i dnt dnt know if nodejs 4.x is not really run on windows ultimate. seems like the socket is use by another program but i dnt know what program.

Answer (score 2):

Try these steps:

1.Open Command Prompt as Administrator

2.Run `netsh winsock reset`