# AssignProcessToJobObject: (87) The parameter is incorrect. node js javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, exec

Hi Guys this is my first question i am asking on stack overflow so please help me if you know the solution.

The problem is i am using exec in node.js to run basic ls command but whenever i run it, shows me AssignProcessToJobObject: (87) The parameter is incorrect. i have tested the rest of the functions which is calling it but could not find any solution. Please help me if you know how to solve this bug thanks.

```
  exec("ls -la", (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) reject({ error });
    if (stderr) reject({ stderr });
    resolve(stdout);
  });
```

Comment: follow this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-launch-child-processes-in-node-js

Comment: Since you using Windows, are you sure that `ls -la` actually is a working command? I cannot test this for you since I do not have node installed on a Windows machine.

Comment: If you are using windows ls -la won't work. It will give you an error.  You should use a return statement inside if block otherwise the next line will also get executed. This question is already asked in StackOverflow. Below is the link.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33879825/cant-launch-nodejs-program-socket-87-the-parameter-is-incorrect

Maybe this helps.

Regards,
omi

Comment: I changed the command to echo "hello world" but still it is showing the same error that parameter is incorrect

Comment: I think that exec is not working at all why i don't know i am trying it with cd command or echo but still it is showing parameter is incorrect. Maybe it's windows problem or node.js problem

Comment: `echo` is not a program. Try `ping localhost`.